# Client sending the same message again and again

Tags: android

I'm developing a client app for Android. When it's connected to the server through socket it sends a message. The problem is that it keeps on sending the message even though it's the same.

Here's the code I've used so far.

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        out.println(sendMsg.getText().toString());
                        out.flush();
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error!", e);
                }
            }
            //Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do add this `if (out.toString()==sendMsg.getText().toString()){
                                connected=false;
                                out.flush();
                            };` but the result is still the same.
How can I make it send a message only if it's different than the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compare string with `equals();`

change `==` with `equals();`

```
if (out.toString().equals(sendMsg.getText().toString()))
{ 
connected=false; out.flush(); 

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a defect in your while loop.

There is no condition that sets connected to false, so it goes one forever.

Just out of curiosity: is there a reason you are doing a socket connection instead of the http or https?

Comment: No, I just started learning socket first.

I have condition but it is not working properly.

Comment: If i might give you some advice: you don't need to know anything about sockets, unless you really need to know about sockets. Whatever you are trying to accomplish you should be able to do with http or https connections. Android has a TON of classes for that kind of communication. And if you are building up the server at the same time then you can easily support those connections with about a billion times more security.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will check on http/https connections. Just to finish this project.